# How can I get kubectl to recognize the newly scaled az aks nodepool nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I updated my Azure AKS nodepool size from within the Azure Portal to go from 2 to 4 nodes. When I run `az aks nodepool show ...`, I see that the count has correctly been updated. However, when I run `kubectl get nodes`, I still only see the two nodes that previously existed.

According to [the Kubernetes documentation on node management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#management),

> There are two main ways to have Nodes added to the API server :
>
> 1. **The kubelet on a node self-registers to the control plane**
> 2. You, or another human user, manually add a Node object

(Emphasis mine)

My expectation, therefore, is that having scaled up my node pool, these new nodes should automatically register, and `kubectl get nodes` should just pick them up, but this appears to not be the case.

Now that my nodepool has more nodes, how do I get my AKS cluster to recognize and utilize them? Once `kubectl get nodes` shows them, will applying an updated manifest (with more replicas) be all I need to do to use the additional hardware?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see without access to your setup. But you can see:

- Check that the control plane hasn't been automatically upgraded to a new version that is incompatible with the kubelet version in your nodepool when it registers with the cluster. (Best if the versions match)
- Connect to the nodes that are not registering (ssh) and check the logs as to why the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#:%7E:text=Synopsis,object%20that%20describes%20a%20pod.) is not starting. i.e `systectl status kubelet`.
- Check that you can connect to the port (i.e `8443`) and IP address where your [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) is listening on from these nodes that are not registering. i.e `curl <ip-address>:8443`

Possible solution:

- Upgrade the VM image of your node pool to use one compatible with the control plane.
- Remove firewall rule preventing your nodes accessing the kube-apiserver

> will applying an updated manifest (with more replicas) be all I need to do to use the additional hardware?

Should work.

✌️